# What's the best way to check for a validation request error with PHPUnit?

Tags: laravel, validation, request, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit to test for a validation error in Laravel. I've set up a custom `Request` and trying to assert that invalid data returns a `403`, but the test throws a `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException : The given data was invalid.` exception before I can `assertStatus`.

I'd like to test for both the response and the exception, so I'd like the test to continue after the exception is thrown (and so that I can check that the resource hasn't actually been created). How can I get the test to acknowledge the exception but continue through the test? Code below.

```php
$this->post('/api/endpoint', [
                'parameter1' => 10]) // Invalid data
                 ->assertStatus(403); // ValidationException is thrown before we get to here
```

Comment: looks like you already using validation some data was invalid??

Comment: care to post your code?

Comment: Apologies, posted.

Comment: I suggest that you use different approach such as `$this->post('/api/endpoint', ['parameter1' => 10])->assertSessionHasErrors('parameter1');`

Comment: @MichaelNguyen I've changed the code to `assertSessionHasErrors`, but the actual Laravel validation is still throwing an `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException` so the logic is never executed.

Comment: do you have `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @MichaelNguyen No I don't. Adding it to the test doesn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193927/discussion-between-michael-nguyen-and-alex-godbehere).